# Crystal Reports PostgreSQL inet query

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a report that allows a user to select a branch that they want to view traffic for in Crystal Reports 11.

The data type in question is of the inet data type in PostgreSQL, I cannot change it.  Because of this, it appears as though the "Like" operator will not work correctly.

About the Inet Data Type: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-net.html

It would be simple if I could get crystal reports to simply use the "<<" operator as defined on the PostgreSQL site, but I cannot figure out how to do this.  Is it possible to force the SQL query to use a specific operator instead of Crystal Reports narrow, and completely insufficient selection?

Comment: I cannot add, remove, or change stored procedures on the specified database server.  If I could, then I would have already done this.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a stored procedure from Crystal Reports? If so, just wrap your query inside a stored procedure and return the result to CR.